# Remove first element from a multi-dimension array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like :

```
var arr = [["series0","44","24",56,12 ]]
```

How to trim(remove) the first element, here it is  **"series0"** ?
I already tried most predefined js function but could not find solution.
Thanks all for great answers.What would be best way to sort the array, i already tried for:

```
.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
```

and also:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});
```

I need the sort result should return like arr=[["series0","12","24","44","56"]]
Rather i am getting [["12","24","44","56","series0"]]

Comment: `arr[0] = arr[0].splice(0, 1);`

Comment: check out my answer.

Comment: @Tushar how about `arr[0].shift()`

Comment: `arr[0].shift()` is simpler

Comment: @Tushar, no assignment necessary, the splice returns the spliced part/s.

Comment: arr[0].shift() or arr[0].splice(0, 1) both worked fine..

Comment: @user3172663,  What about me? I did the answer at the right time but not get voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**, by changing second parameter you can remove more than one elements

```js
var arr = [
  ["series0", "44", "54", 56]
];
arr[0].splice(0, 1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

**EDIT :** In case if you just want to remove single element then **[`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)** will be best solution

```js
var arr = [
  ["series0", "44", "54", 56]
];
arr[0].shift();

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: i am curious, if i can sort the same array type that contain both string and integer.Lets say the array is like this                                        var arr = [ ["series0", "44", "32", 56]];
After sort i would like to get the array like 
var arr= [["series0", "32", "44", 56]]

Comment: @user3172663 : use  [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I am trying for 
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});  but could not get the result as i am expecting.You can find the first element of the array is string and others are integers.

Comment: @user3172663 : add another question with relevant code

Answer (score 3):

The `shift` method removes the first element, you can call it on the first element of your array:

```
arr[0].shift()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `.map` function of `Array`:

```
var arr = [["series0", "44", "54",56 ]]
arr.map(function(arr){arr.shift()});
console.log(arr)
```

It'll remove all the first element of all elements of outer array.

input:

```
 [["series0", "44", "54",56 ],["series0", "44", "54",56 ]]
```

output:

```
[["44", "54",56 ],["44", "54",56 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use the shift function:**

Removes the first element from an array and returns only that element.

```
arr[0].shift();
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array shift() method:

```
var arr = [["series0", "44", "54",56 ]]
arr[0].shift();      // removes and returns "series0" (return ignored here)
```